# Re-use the deleted sequences of primary keys (BIGSERIAL) - No UUID to save storage

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence, primary-key, alter

I am using `BIGSERIAL` as a **Primary key** and I want to make use of the deleted row's ids.

Example of the table that I want re-use the deleted ids from the deleted rows:

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id=3;
INSERT INTO my_table(column_x) VALUES(xxxxx)
```

my_table

```
| id|column_x|        | id|column_x|               | id|column_x|
|---|--------|        |---|--------|               |---|--------|
| 1 | xxxxxx |        | 1 | xxxxxx |               | 1 | xxxxxx |
| 2 | xxxxxx |        | 2 | xxxxxx |               | 2 | xxxxxx |
| 3 | xxxxxx |   >>>  | 4 | xxxxxx |        >>>    | 4 | xxxxxx |
| 4 | xxxxxx |        | 5 | xxxxxx |               | 5 | xxxxxx |
| 5 | xxxxxx |                                     | 3 | xxxxxx |
```

The third table from the right inserted a new row with the id=3 in which was deleted in the table in the middle, and by doing so. I want to make use of those skipped sequences.

I made a few attempts by using `ALTER SEQUENCE` [source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-altersequence.html)

***My current solution:***

```
 INSERT INTO my_table(id, column_x)
 VALUES(deleted_index, xxxx);
```

**Expected solution:**

```
INSERT INTO my_table(column)
VALUES(xxxx);
```

In other words, altering the sequence for the index my_table.id so it re-uses the deleted sequences and move on to `nextval`

Comment: Why? Sequence values should be taken as having no meaning other then to be unique and incrementing(not gapless).

Comment: The only job of a generated primary key is to be unique. The actual values is completely irrelevant. The value 1 is just as good as 36947648, -34234 or 93. There is nothing you need to do. Just move on.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver UUID will consume extra storage where as BIGSERIAL is not

Comment: You will need a trigger to keep track of deleted ids in a table and another trigger that picks ids from there. You don't want to go that way.

Comment: I did not say anything about using `UUID`.  A `BIGSERIAL Primary key` column is meant to be a unique number generator that has no meaning other then that.

Comment: In “from the right inserted a new column”, did you mean to say “new row”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dot not understand the purpose of this, but there is the code, surprisingly it works fine:

```
WITH selectvalues AS (
SELECT * FROM my_table 
),
deletevalue AS (
DELETE FROM my_table  del
    USING selectvalues sel
    WHERE del.id = sel.id
    RETURNING del.*
),
insertval AS(
INSERT INTO my_table 
SELECT * FROM deletevalue
RETURNING * )
SELECT * FROM insertval
```

Comment: The purpose isn't going to add much in the performance wise but more of storage for an application that inserts numerous amount of values per second. I will try your solution. Thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really think you will exhaust all 9223372036854775807 positive `bigint` numbers? Any attempt to "fill the gaps" will complicate matters and be bad for performance.

Comment: This's a challenging application request and to save storage from using UUID.As for the inserts! it's a quite numerous inserts per second. "This is a fool's errand" on the other hand, is totally unnecessary and unproductive comment! Please try more polite comment. Thank you!

Comment: "Fools errand" is a turn of phrase and not intended to imply that you are a fool. I have removed it. Sure, you don't want UUIDs, that makes perfect sense to me. But what is wrong with gaps in your sequence of `id`s? After all, these are automatically generated artificial primary keys and have no meaning outside the database.